# Rookie mistake in defining a function with Modules?

Tags: programming, function-construction

I can't figure out what's wrong with this piece of code. I'm trying to define a function that counts the occurrences of `x`, `y` and `l` or `lc` in expressions like `x[x[y[l]]`, where `x` will add 1 to an "eigenvalue", `y` will subtract 1 and likewise for `l` and `lc`. Then for example I would get `H[x[x[y[l]]] = 2`. Now I'm stuck at the first phase with the function defined below:

```
H[z_] := Module[{list1 = Join[Level[z, Infinity], {z}], lam = 0},
  Which[list1[[1]] == l, lam = lam + 1, 
        list1[[1]] == lc, lam = lam - 1
  ];
  lam
]
```

This should give `H[l] = 1` and `H[lc] = -1`, but instead I get just the initial value `lam = 0` for the "lc" case... When I discard the last line and use instead

```
H[z_] := Module[{list1 = Join[Level[z, Infinity], {z}], lam = 0},
  Which[list1[[1]] == l, lam = lam + 1, 
        list1[[1]] == lc, lam = lam - 1
  ]
]
```

I get

```
Which[lc == l, lam$538474 = lam$538474 + 1, 
      list1$538474[[1]] == lc, lam$538474 = lam$538474 - 1
]
```

Clearly something's wrong with the `list1$538474[[1]]` above. What am I missing?

Comment: I quit and restarted the kernel and nothing!! This is beginning to seem really strange...

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing"? No change? No output?

Comment: Still gives H[lc]=0...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `SameQ` (`===`) instead of `Equal` (`==`).  `Equal` of two symbols will return unevaluated (so neither `True` nor `False`) causing `Which` to return unevaluated:

> If any of the $test_i$ evaluated by `Which` give neither `True` nor `False`, then a `Which` object containing these remaining elements is returned unevaluated.

```
Which[foo == foo, 1, foo == bar, 2]

(* ==> 1 *)

Which[foo == bar, 1, foo == foo, 2]

(* ==> Which[foo == bar, 1, foo == foo, 2] *)
```

Comment: 5 secs too late...

Comment: He could also use `TrueQ[foo==bar]`

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch `True`, although that requires more typing. :-)

Comment: sure does. exhausting :) . Was just wanting to cover all the bases in any case.

Comment: That works great, thanks Brett!! :)