# Testing equality of graphics

Tags: plotting, core-language

Is there a way to reliably test the equality of two plots?  Consider this:

```
plot1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2Pi}];
plot2 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2Pi}];
```

You'd think these would be equal, but they're not.

```
Evaluate[plot1 == plot2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`SameQ` doesn't work either:

```
Evaluate[plot1 === plot2]
(* False *)
```

At least this works:

```
Evaluate[plot1 == plot1]
(* True *)
```

**Edit:**

@eyorble provided a nice answer, but the plot thickens.  How can we also get `False` when two plots are not equal?

```
plot3 = Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2Pi}];
(plot1 == plot3) /. (x_String :> StringReplace[x, "Charting`Private`Tag$" ~~ __ -> "Charting`Private`Tag"])
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: The newer versions add some sort of unique tag each time Plot is executed. Makes comparison pretty much impossible

Comment: Any thoughts on a workaround?

Comment: Removing the tag (or remapping it as in the answer) would work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
plot1 == plot2 /. 
  (x_String :> StringReplace[x, "Charting`Private`Tag$" ~~ __ -> "Charting`Private`Tag"])
```

> True

Plots seem to be otherwise deterministic, so that appears to be the only necessary change for comparison with `==`.

To get `False` when they aren't equal, perhaps something like this would suffice:

```
Activate[Inactive[SameQ][plot1, plot2]
   /. (x_String :> StringReplace[x, "Charting`Private`Tag$" ~~ __ -> "Charting`Private`Tag"])]
```

`Inactive` and `Activate` are simply to ensure that `SameQ` doesn't evaluate before the replacement takes place.

Comment: Thanks!  I realized another important case is to get `False` when two plots are not equal.  See my edit to the question.  Any ideas there?

Comment: @ChrisK Updated my answer for that.

Comment: Seems to work.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 7):

As I [observed earlier](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37737239#37737239), the tags are used in plots in the form [`Annotation[curve, tag]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Annotation.html) for each function plotted.  One way to just get the curves is to override `Annotation`:

```
Block[{Annotation = #1 &},
 plot1 == plot2
 ]
(*  True  *)

Block[{Annotation = #1 &},
 plot1 === plot2
 ]
(*  True  *)
```

Since the tags are in the `` Charting`Private` `` context, it seems pointless to have them in the first place.  (Even if they are used in constructing the plot, what good are they in the final output, ostensibly private and hidden from the user?)

*Note on `Equal` vs. `SameQ`:*
`Equal` will evaluate to `True` when expressions are the same (as in `SameQ`), but it tends to remain unevaluated if there are symbols (which might take on arbitrary values).  To be sure to get a `False`, use `SameQ`:

```
Plus == Automatic
(*  Plus == Automatic  *)

Plus === Automatic
(*  False  *)
```

See [1 is not the SameQ as Null, but why might 1 be Equal to Null?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/159648/1-is-not-the-sameq-as-null-but-why-might-1-be-equal-to-null)

Also related: [(4390)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4390), [(8796)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8796), [(17909)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17909).

Comment: I have a Hash@expr based caching procedure for my APIFunctions and now I need to patch it because of that -.- I'd call it a minor bug.

Answer (score 3):

If by equal you mean the plots look the same and are the same size then you can use [`Rasterize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rasterize.html) and [`ImageData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageData.html).

```
samePlot[p1_, p2_] := Equal @@ (ImageData@Rasterize[#, "Image"] & /@ {p1, p2})
```

With

```
plot1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}];
plot2 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}];
plot3 = Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}];
```

Then

```
samePlot[plot1, plot2]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
samePlot[plot1, plot3]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great, this helps me with [a related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/165533/notification-if-new-output-differs-from-old).